# WSO2 - Identity Server / API Manager - Configuring Identity Server as External IDP using OIDC

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I a trying to apply the tutorial under WSO2 documentation link: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/sso/configuring-identity-server-as-external-idp-using-oidc/

In one of the steps, while explaning a checkbox, i saw that they used a federated authentication type named 'is'. The config of 'is' is not explained in the same tutorial, is it required to perform the external IDP flow? or is it optional? if required, can someone please provide the tutorial link containing the configuration of 'is'?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here `is` the name you provided for 'Federated IDP'. You can refer to this Medium Blog for detailed explanation. In the blog, they explain with two identity servers. In your scenario, you can also refer to the same blog and use WSO2 APIM as the Internal IDP.

Medium Blog : https://medium.com/@methmas/federated-authentication-with-wso2-identity-server-with-openid-protocol-and-wso2-playground2-app-212151d66f7a